# Possible to use Kendo Ui Ng2 Modal like the old Ui-Bootrap Modal from ng1

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

In ng1 it was possible without having any directive directly on my page to call the modal from which was defined somewhere else.

I've created my own modal Service, where I defined many modals and I was able to open them from every view where I injected the service.

example of one of my Service Functions to open a modal

```
    public editTodoItem(id: Number): ng.IPromise<My.ITodoCreateViewModel> {
        var options: ng.ui.bootstrap.IModalSettings = {
            templateUrl: 'Todo/TodoEditModal',
            bindToController : true,
            controller: "todoEditModalCtrl",
            controllerAs : 'ctrl',
            size: 'lg',
            backdrop: "static",
            resolve: {
                todoId: () => id
            }
        };

        return this.$uibModal.open(options).result
            .then((updatedItem: My.ITodoCreateViewModel) => {
            return updatedItem;
        });
    }
```

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

and when I closed the modal It returns a promise where i can send also some data with to the calling function.

is this also possible with the Modal from Kendo Ui?

the new implementation from ui Bootstrap for Ng2 seems to have this feature implemented already

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pending feature of the Kendo UI for Angular 2 dialog component. Track its status in the [public issue repo](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/112).